Eigenvalues of the sum of outer products
I have a matrix in the form of a weighted sum of outer products $$W=\sum_{s=1}^n k_sa_sa_s^T$$ where $a_s\in \mathbb{R}^d,k_s\in\mathbb{R}$. We also have $n\geq d$.
What can we say about the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix? Or can we provide some lower bound on the eigenvalues based on $k_s,s=1,...,n$?
A special case was previously discussed here, where $k_1=1$ and $k_s=2$ for $s\geq 2$.
This structure can arise from the online learning setting, where the vectors $a_s$ are sequentially selected, and each selection leads to some reward. To theoretically analyze the estimation error and thus the cumulative reward, I'm particularly interested in the smallest eigenvalue of the matrix. In this setting $n$ represent the number of vectors that are already selected.

You need to put more conditions to have a useful answer. Already with $n = d$ it is possible to represent every diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(k_1, \dots, k_d) = \sum_{s = 1}^d k_s e_s e_s^\top$, and with $n = \frac{d(d + 1)}{2}$ it is possible to represent every symmetric matrix.

This question doesn’t meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not help the user by posting this answer rather as a comment suggesting improvements? Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
